# Rails stimulus-autocomplete Errors - Uncaught Error: Module parse failed - Static Targets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm still relatively new to the Rails game, but I was wondering whether anyone could assist with a problem that I have.

I wanted to implement `[stimulus-autocomplete][1]` into my rails 6 app, but when I follow the instructions laid out, I get an error in my console, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

My `javascript/controllers/index.js` file looks like so:

```
import { Application } from "stimulus"
import { definitionsFromContext } from "stimulus/webpack-helpers"
import { Autocomplete } from 'stimulus-autocomplete'

const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context("controllers", true, /_controller\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
application.register('autocomplete', Autocomplete)
```

I've run `yarn add stimulus-autocomplete` and rebooted my server, but I now get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| export default class Autocomplete extends Controller {
>   static targets = ["input", "hidden", "results"]
|   static classes = ["selected"]
|   static values = {
    at ./node_modules/stimulus-autocomplete/src/autocomplete.js (bootstrap.esm.js:4999:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./app/javascript/controllers/index.js (index.js:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at bootstrap:83:1
    at bootstrap:83:1
```

I think it's an issue with the static targets themselves and possibly something to do with support in ES6, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I'm using `webpack` on the application.

If anyone has any pointers, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you're absolutely correct re: ES6. I had a similar error today and resolved it by adding

```
"babel": { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

To the end of my package.json file - after devDependencies (you may need to add @babel/preset-env via Yarn as well.)

There are also some differences with babel and Webpacker versions, so if the above doesn't work it might be best to add version numbers to your answer.